# integration and convolution

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, signal-processing

Please can some one help me on the following integration.

$$
G(\nu)=\frac{1}{\Delta t}\int_{t_a - \frac{\Delta t}{2}}^{t_a + \frac{\Delta t}{2}} f(t_a -t)e^{-2\pi\nu it}dt
$$

where $f(x)=\mbox{sinc}(x)$;

I can see that the is some relationship with the convolution, but I am able to solve only for $f(t_a-t)=1$

Comment: Did you mean $f(x)=\sin (cx)$?

Comment: @MarioG: usually $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$ is defined as $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$ and as $1$ if $x=0$.

Comment: However, in this form $G(\nu)$ depends on $\Delta t$, too, not only on $\nu$. Is $G(\nu)$ defined as the limit for $\Delta t\to 0^+$ of such expression?

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying a bit the expression we have:
$$ G(\nu) = \frac{e^{-2\pi \nu i t_a}}{\Delta t}\int_{-\Delta t/2}^{\Delta t/2}f(-t)e^{-2\pi\nu i t}\,dt$$
and since $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$ is an even function we have:
$$ G(\nu) = \frac{2 e^{-2\pi \nu i t_a}}{\Delta t}\int_{0}^{\Delta t/2}f(-t)\cos(2\pi\nu  t)\,dt$$
and since in a right neighbourhood of zero both $f(-t)$ and $\cos(2\pi\nu t)$ behave like $1+o(t)$, by letting $\Delta t\to 0^+$ we simply have
$$ G(\nu) = e^{-2\pi\nu i t_a} $$
due to the integral version of the mean value theorem.